# Finding duplicate values in a table where all the columns are not the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with a set of data in a table. 
For simplicity i have the table like below with some sample data:

[image]

Some of the data in this table came from a different source, such data are the ones that have `cqmRecordID != null`

I need to find duplicate values in this table and delete the duplicate ones that came over from the other source (ones with a cqmRecordID)
A record is considered duplicate if they have the same values for these cols:

- [Name]
- Cast([CreatedDate] as Date)
- [CreatedBy]

So in the sample data i have above, record #5 and record #6 would be considered duplicates.

As solutions I came up with these two queries:

**Query #1:**

```
 select * from (
  select recordid, cqmrecordid, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by name, cast(createddate as date), createdby 
                                                   order by cqmrecordid, recordid) as rownum
  from vmsNCR  ) A
  where cqmrecordid is not null   
  order by recordid
```

[image]

**Query #2:**

```
  select A.recordID, A.cqmRecordID, B.RecordID, B.cqmRecordID 
  from vmsNCR A 
  join vmsNCR B
    on A.Name = B.Name 
    and cast(A.CreatedDate as date) = cast(B.CreatedDate as date) 
    and A.CreatedBy = B.CreatedBy
    and A.RecordID != B.RecordID 
    and A.cqmRecordID is not null 
  order by A.RecordID
```

[image]

Is there a better approach to this?  Is one better than the other performance wise?

Comment: So what is the problem with those queries?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza not having a problem with the query.. but just wondering if this is the best approach..this is only sample data.. i will have a large dataset.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: arent `{1,3}` also duplicates?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza no .. those won't be duplicates.. because i only consider a record to be duplicate if it came over from the different data source (one with cqmRecordNumber not null)

Comment: Can you have a not null duplicated record without a null record? So the only data is the not null so isnt really duplicated?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch all the rows without duplicates, then:

```
select t.*  -- or all columns except seqnum
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name, cast(createddate as date), createdby
                                order by (case when cqmRecordId is not null then 1 else 2 end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want performance, create a columns and then an index:

```
alter table t add cqmRecordId_flag as (case when cqmRecordId is null then 0 else 1 end) persisted;
alter table t add createddate_date as (cast(createddate as date)) persisted;
```

And then an index:

```
create index idx_t_4 on t(name, createddate_date, createdby, cqmRecordId_flag desc);
```

EDIT:

If you actually just want to delete the `NULL` values from the table, you can use:

```
delete t from t
    where t.cqmRecordId is null and
          exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.name = t.name and
                        convert(date, t2.createddate_date) =convert(date, t.createddate_date) and
                        t2.createdby = t.createdby and
                        t2.cqmRecordId is not null
                 );
```

You can use the same logic with `select` to just select the duplicates.

Comment: Maybe you want use rank() instead of row_number()  in case multiple duplicates?

Comment: Also  this bring the one without duplicates too.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . I assume the OP really wants to fetch the rows without duplicates, but I updated the answer.

Comment: Looking OP desire result (in the pictures) he return `{5,6}` what he consider be the duplcates

Comment: He want delete the not null duplicates. So the logic is inverted.

Comment: I changed the query u had a little bit inorder to get the result i want.. like Juan mentioned I only want 5 and 6 to come back as duplicates... 
`select t.*  -- or all columns except seqnum
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name, cast(createddate as date), createdby
                                order by (case when cqmRecordId is not null then 1 else 2 end) desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum != 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to eliminate duplicates

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
              PARTITION BY [Name],Cast([CreatedDate] as Date),[CreatedBy] 
              ORDER BY cqmRecordId
           ) AS Rnk
   ,*
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE Rnk <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below Query it might work for You

```
;WITH TestCTE
AS
(
   SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
              PARTITION BY [Name],Cast([CreatedDate] as Date),[CreatedBy] 
              ORDER BY RecordId
            ) AS RowNumber
)
DELETE FROM TestCTE
WHERE RowNumber > 1
```